# How to show illegal whitespace (such as unbreakable space) in source code?

Tags: highlight, unicode, whitespace

I sometimes type (by accident) shift-space, inserting unbreakable space into code. With c++, I get this:

```
error: stray ‘\302’ in program
error: stray ‘\240’ in program
```

while in other formats (like RestructuredText), I am hunting mysterious errors of syntax without any visible cause.

Is there a way to

- always highlight unbreakable spaces (and perhaps other type of "illegal" whitespace, i.e. any whitespace besides space and tab)
- map shift-space to space, so that these characters are not inserted in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## List & Listchars

`'list'` is a boolean option that, when `set`, instructs vim to display whitespace characters. And it is completely customizable using `'listchars'`.

For example, to show non-breaking spaces as `!` (you can use whatever character you like, especially with digraphs and unicode support):

```
set list listchars=nbsp:!
```

I use `'listchars'` extensively, since it supports tabs, trailing whitespace, and more. It helps provide little background indicators that things aren't really what they seem.

My [current settings](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/vimrc#L120-#L121), for example, are

```
set list listchars=tab:»\ ,trail:·,nbsp:⎵,precedes:<,extends:>
```

Meaning:

- tabs show as `»` followed by spaces ;
- trailing white spaces show up as dots ;
- non-breaking spaces show up as that weird unicode space character ;
- if the line wraps to the left or the right, I get angle-bracket notifiers

---

Further Reading:

- `:h 'list'`
- `:h 'listchars'`

Comment: This is also useful in languages like Python or GNU Make where whitespace is significant and the difference between four spaces and a tab can make a big difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
:syntax match ErrorMsg " "
```

while inserting an unbreakable space between the `"`'s.

To automatically load the rule, you can simply add

```
au VimEnter,BufWinEnter * syn match ErrorMsg " "
```

to your `.vimrc`.

If you want to customize the highlighting, create a custom rule before the `syn match`, i.e.

```
highlight UnbreakableSpace ctermbg=red guibg=red
au VimEnter,BufWinEnter * syn match UnbreakableSpace " "
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use the `<S-Space>` notation in a mapping* but I think you should be able to map it by pressing <kbd>Shift+Space</kbd> when typing in the mapping where I've written `[lhs]` below:

```
:inoremap [lhs] <Space>
```

Of course, when reading your `.vimrc`, this will be a bit confusing, so you might be better off using an `:execute` command and Vim's notation for adding Unicode characters to a string:

```
execute "inoremap \u00A0 <Space>"
```

(N.B. I'm not entirely sure which character you are inserting when you press <kbd>Shift+Space</kbd>: you may need to adjust the Unicode value accordingly.)

<sub>* I think that the keystrokes are probably converted in your terminal and never make it to Vim. So Vim only sees the unbreakable space: it doesn't know you pressed `Shift+Space`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I do have this in my custom vimrc file, which highlights git conflict markers as well as special whitespace characters.

```
" highlight VCS conflict markers
" highlight strange Whitespace
aug CustomHighlighting
  au!
  au WinEnter * if !exists("w:custom_hi1") | let w:custom_hi1 = matchadd('ErrorMsg', '^\(<\|=\|>\)\{7\}\([^=].\+\)\?$') | endif
  au WinEnter * if !exists("w:custom_hi2") | let w:custom_hi2 = matchadd('ErrorMsg', '[\x0b\x0c\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]') |  endif
aug END
```

kudos to Benjamin Haskell via the [vim_use mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/FuEGojGwKCM/V1K8VAWWKrEJ)